# PHP foreach not adding to variable when using +=

Tags: php, foreach

I am getting an unexpected result from the following bit of code:

```
$minutes = 0;
if($timeSpan === "game") {
  //stuff
} elseif($timeSpan === "season") {
  $games = Game::where('season_id', $timeSpanId)->where('team_id', $whoId)->where('stats_done', 'yes');
  foreach($games as $game) {
    $minutes += $game->periods * $game->period_length * 5;
  }
}

return $minutes;
```

This returns 0, but I know that isn't what I am trying to get and the DB has the data there so this shouldn't be the case.

Quick context:

- $timeSpan does equal "season", and after testing, I know this isn't the problem
- The Game query here does return results. I know because I took out the foreach and replaced it with $minutes = $games->count() and got 5

Anybody have a clue what this could be? I feel like I've had this problem with foreach loops before, so I look forward to understanding where my knowledge of them is lacking.

Thank you!

Comment: you are missing `->get()` which should be at the end of the query

Comment: In PHP Use .= To add variable

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you! Put that as an answer so I can mark it correct please!

Comment: @HarishKarthick What is the difference between the two?

Comment: .= append it as text, + adds it as number, `+=` is the right one to use here.

Comment: Normally in java or JavaScript we use += to dynamically add variable in PHP we need to use .=

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I commented, actually you are just missing `get()` which will retrieve the result of executed query. So kindly execute as following

```
$games = Game::where('season_id', $timeSpanId)->where('team_id', $whoId)->where('stats_done', 'yes')->get();
```

Comment: my bad dude, stepped away for a minute and then a day went by. Just marked it